# custom query var NOT working on a plain permalink: http://10.8.10.9/?page_id=1774/?location=968&floor=1

Tags: permalinks

I used to have a working custom query for location on this **local** link:

```
http://website.local/catalogue/?location=968&floor=1
```

but, the server that I had to move to (Linux) it appears that is not supporting Permalinks->Post name (http://10.8.10.9/sample-post/) only the default Plain (http://10.8.10.9/?p=123), so I the link changed to this:

```
http://10.8.10.9/?page_id=1774/?location=968&floor=1
```

The problem is: location does not work anymore, but floor does. I guess that's because I have basically **two** **"?"** on the link.

How can I resolve this frustrating issue? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `?` sign starts the actual query string. You can **only have one querystring** where every parameter is separated by a `&` sign, so the above should be `http://10.8.10.9/?page_id=1774&location=968&floor=1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should really try to make the permalinks work on your server. It seldom fails. Have you checked all your server settings are correct, and have you visited the permalink page after updating, so that the cache is flushed?

Otherwise you would have to have `http://10.8.10.9/?page_id=1774&location=968&floor=1` and that would work too.

I'd really try to get the permalink issue fixed first though. It should work on any server really.

Comment: yes "&location" is the way to go :) Thank you very much! Did not think about writing like that :D 
I would give you a vote, but since I don't have 15 reputation, I cannot :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know why the server doesn't allow Post name for Permalinks, not sure what "all your server settings" might be. Please provide more info, if you please :)

Comment: See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks, basically if you're on an Apache server you need mod_rewrite enbaled.

Comment: Make sure to restart Apache after enabling the module too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your link needs to be `http://10.8.10.9/?page_id=1774&location=968&floor=1` having multiple `?` within your request is the problem.